# table cell is not called

Tags: swift, uitableview

I created a UIViewController containing a UITableView. 
I want it to display files I created at another position.

The corresponding class looks like this:

```
import UIKit

class BackupViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

var rows:[String] = []


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.table.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    self.table.dataSource = self
    self.table.delegate = self
    getFiles()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

func getFiles() {
    let filemgr = FileManager.default
    let path = filemgr.urls(for: FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory, in: FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask).last
    do {
        rows = try filemgr.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: (path?.path)!)
        // process files
    } catch {
        print("Error while enumerating files")
    }
    table.reloadData()
}




func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return rows.count
}



func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell:UITableViewCell = self.table.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! UITableViewCell
    cell.textLabel?.text = rows[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}

@IBOutlet weak var table: UITableView!
```

}

It reads the files correctly and when

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int)
```

is called (which happens 3 times for some reason), the array has (at the moment) 2 elements. However, the function

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
```

is never called and of course I get an empty table.

Comment: You forgot to call `table.reloadData()`. Add it after saving the `rows` value and it should work.

Comment: As a side note, please only post _relevant_ code in your questions. `didReceiveMemoryWarning` and the template comment block have *nothing* do do with your question

Comment: edited my post. Had no effect, except that numberOfRows is now called once more

Answer (score 0):

You need to reload your tableView after fetching files in getFile() function.

```
func getFiles() {
        let filemgr = FileManager.default
        let path = filemgr.urls(for: FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory, in: FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask).last
        do {
            rows = try filemgr.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: (path?.path)!)
             self.table.reloadData()
// process files
        } catch {
            print("Error while enumerating files")
        }
        /*for file in files {
            rows.append(file.absoluteString)
        }*/
        showFiles = true
    }
```

You need to call reloadData() once row will have some value in it.

Comment: edited my post. Had no effect, except that numberOfRows is now called once more

Comment: Hey, i tried your code, and work fine for me. check out this link : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1czxbIqj9UpIvKRbVNIlsNt_yLhI9hMm8/view?usp=sharing
i have used your code only.
I got this result, check out image url : https://prnt.sc/jmf4ky